# Switching Organizations in Apple Developer Center

Tags: ios, applet

My apple id is linked with two iOS Developer Accounts. One is my own personal iOS Developer account and one is of office team iOS Developer account. Every time I log in it has the Organization set to that team. I can't switch back to my personal account.
I have also tried directly accessing url: https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/selectTeam.action
but with no luck.

How can I switch back to my personal developer center area?

Answer (score 0):

Login into [**iTunesConnect**](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/). On top right corner, you'll find option (dropdown) to change the organisation.

[image]

After changing that, open [**Apple Developer**](https://developer.apple.com) site (you won't see login screen as iTunesConnect and Apple Developer share the login account). Once you do that, your chosen organisation will be opened.